# Understanding check for 'undefined' document

Tags: javascript

I was just going through the code of **[timesheet.js](https://github.com/sbstjn/timesheet.js/blob/master/source/javascripts/timesheet.js#L16)** and came across the following lines of code:

```
if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
      this.container = (typeof container === 'string') ? document.querySelector('#'+container) : container;
      this.drawSections();
      this.insertData();
    }
```

I totally understand what's going on , except the below line:

```
if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
```

When and Why would the document ever be `undefined` ? What security does this condition add to the plugin ?

I don't understand When and Why would the document ever be `undefined` ? can anybody explain ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: It must be for window.document .. if that is undefined, it will be of no use to use this library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document` would be `undefined` if you were running it in a non-browser environment such as [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

It is related to `window.document`. timesheet.js must using `window.document` for its purposes. Open your JS console and type `document` or `window.document`. If that component is undefined, timesheet will not work.

Comment: OP is asking *why* would `document` be undefined.